# Checking if date is between multiple date ranges

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have 2 dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Bob', 'Jenny', 'Larry', 'Sam', 'Ashley', 'John', 'Bob', 'Jenny', 'Larry', 'Sam', 'Ashley', 'John'], 'start_time': ['2020-06-01 08:01:45', '2020-06-01 08:55:47', '2020-06-01 09:07:00', '2020-06-01 09:12:00', '2020-06-01 09:12:40', '2020-06-01 09:22:05', '2020-06-02 08:01:45', '2020-06-02 08:55:47', '2020-06-02 09:07:00', '2020-06-02 09:12:00', '2020-06-02 09:12:40', '2020-06-02 09:22:05'], 'end_time':['2020-06-01 16:15:00', '2020-06-01 17:00:00', '2020-06-01 17:05:04', '2020-06-01 17:12:12', '2020-06-01 17:45:00', '2020-06-01 19:05:00', '2020-06-02 16:15:00', '2020-06-02 17:00:00', '2020-06-02 17:05:04', '2020-06-02 17:12:12', '2020-06-02 17:45:00', '2020-06-02 19:05:00']})
```

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Bob', 'Bob', 'Jenny', 'Ashley', 'Bob', 'John', 'John', 'Jenny', 'Sam'], 'time': ['2020-06-01 08:07:00', '2020-06-01 08:40:47', '2020-06-01 8:50:00', '2020-06-01 10:10:30', '2020-06-01 14:12:33', '2020-06-01 14:41:33', '2020-06-01 15:12:33', '2020-06-01 18:44:33', '2020-06-01 22:12:07']})
```

I'm trying to check and see if a given `'time'` in `df2` is contained within any time span with the same name (i.e. I'm only trying to check Bob's entries in `df2` against Bob's `'start_time'`s and `'end_time'`s in `df1`) and return a boolean value in a new column in `df2`. Here's what I'd expect as output:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Bob', 'Bob', 'Jenny', 'Ashley', 'Bob', 'John', 'John', 'Jenny', 'Sam'], 'time': ['2020-06-01 08:07:00', '2020-06-01 08:40:47', '2020-06-01 8:50:00', '2020-06-01 10:10:30', '2020-06-01 14:12:33', '2020-06-01 14:41:33', '2020-06-01 15:12:33', '2020-06-01 18:44:33', '2020-06-01 22:12:07'], 'legal': [True, True, False, True, True, True, True, False, False]})
```

I've tried using if functions, but I keep getting a ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do so by doing a left join, compare and then aggregate taking the max of 'legal':

```
df3 = df2.merge(df1, on='name', how='left')

df3['legal'] = (df3['time'] >= df3['start_time']) & (df3['time'] <= df3['end_time'])

print(df3[['name', 'time', 'legal']].groupby(['name', 'time']).max().reset_index())
```

prints

```
     name                 time  legal
0  Ashley  2020-06-01 10:10:30   True
1     Bob  2020-06-01 08:07:00   True
2     Bob  2020-06-01 08:40:47   True
3     Bob  2020-06-01 14:12:33   True
4   Jenny  2020-06-01 18:44:33  False
5   Jenny   2020-06-01 8:50:00  False
6    John  2020-06-01 14:41:33   True
7    John  2020-06-01 15:12:33   True
8     Sam  2020-06-01 22:12:07  False
```

Note: when comparing strings it is important to have consistent formatting of the datetimes.

Comment: This: `x.time >= x.start_time and x.time <= x.end_time` can be written as `x.start_time <= x.time <= x.end_time`

Comment: You are both right, updated the answer with @Ben.T's suggestion

Answer (score 0):

```
res = df2.merge(df1, on='name', how='left').drop_duplicates( subset='time', keep='first').sort_values(by='name')
res['legal']=res['time'].between(res['start_time'],res['end_time'])
res.drop(columns=['start_time','end_time'], inplace=True)
```

print(res)

```
     name                 time  legal
6   Ashley  2020-06-01 10:10:30   True
0      Bob  2020-06-01 08:07:00   True
2      Bob  2020-06-01 08:40:47   True
8      Bob  2020-06-01 14:12:33   True
4    Jenny   2020-06-01 8:50:00  False
14   Jenny  2020-06-01 18:44:33  False
10    John  2020-06-01 14:41:33   True
12    John  2020-06-01 15:12:33   True
16     Sam  2020-06-01 22:12:07  False
```